# ObservableCollection and displaying its data question, Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I am developing a part of my app where I need to take images I have in the phone (user downloads them with the application) and displaying them in a databound listbox. Let us call this Page1.

However, I want to be able to add to this collection when a user "favorites" an image from my RSS feed. Let us call this page 2.

So in essence, I want to combine Page1 items and Page2 items, and display them on Page1. I also want to be able to allow users to remove any of the images they like from being shown.

I am uncertain how to go about this. Do I create a separate class, and write all the items to a file in isolated storage?

mock code (since not on my app computer)

```
public class Imagelist : ObservableCollection<Images>
{
  public Imagelist() : base()
  {
    //add items from page1.
    //add items from page2.

    Add(new Images("Imagepath"));
    ...    
  }
}
```

... get/set the pathing, maybe by setting all the images into a key?

Not sure, but definitely could use some insight.

Comment: I realize that it's mock code, but the class doesn't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, since ObservableCollection already implements it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: thank you. I have taken it out.

Comment: so how should I go about getting the paths of the images that come with the phone, as well as joining them with ones pulled from the internet marked as favorited

Comment: How does your `ImageList` class relate to Page1 and Page2?

Comment: Sorry for not fully understanding this, but I'll do my best to answer the question. The class relates to both pages in that I simply want to use it as a way of combining Stock photo paths, which will come with the app, with image URLs which can be selectively saved by the user from the RSS feed.

Comment: In essence, a union of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing the ImageList as a singleton should work. I've created a short example that adds strings instead of images.

```
void Main()
{
   var page1 = new Page1();
   var page2 = new Page2();

   foreach (var txt in ImageList.Instance)
   {
        Console.WriteLine (txt);
        // prints:
        // Instance created
        // page1
        // page2
   }
}

public class ImageList : ObservableCollection<string>
{
    private static ImageList _instance;
    public static ImageList Instance 
    { 
        get
        {
            if(_instance==null)
            {
                _instance = new ImageList();
                _instance.Add("Instance created");      
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private ImageList() 
    {
    }
}

public class Page1
{
    public Page1()
    {
        ImageList.Instance.Add("page1");
    }
}

public class Page2
{
    public Page2()
    {
        ImageList.Instance.Add("page2");
    }
}
```

Comment: This should essentially work I feel too: I have the filepath of the device images set up as a string, so I can regurgitate the string as the image source.  This would also work with the RSS feed, as I can add the URL of the image to string on Page 2, and then combine it all to show on page 1. Since I am not at my app computer now, would there be a way to incorporate this into isolated storage? Is it possible to add the code into it?

Comment: and because I am still very new to using silverlight.. would the Void Main() function be called when navigating to the Page1?. Would the public classes Page1 and Page2 be in the same class C# document?

Comment: 1st comment: What do you mean? Save the ImageList instance to IsolatedStorage?


2nd comment: The Main method was just included to show a working example. You only need the ImageList class and use it in the different classes where you'll need it.